# Angular send array of objects(multi dimensions array) in GET query

Tags: angular, form-data, angular-httpclient

**Problem**: How to send GET request with Angular's `HttpClient` with array of objects e.g

```
[{a: "a", b: "b"}, {a: "c", b: "d"}];
```

in `FormData` format like

```
test[][test]: a
test[][test]: c
test[][lol]: b
test[][lol]: d
```

so the final result of operation should be (in url decoded form):

```
GET /?test[][test]=a&test[][test]=c&test[][lol]=b&test[][lol]=d
```

**Question**:
I managed to build working solution but it's look hacky and that problem looks *kinda* common, so there should be better and cleaner solution to solve that problem in elegant way with use of Angular tools. Or sending that type of data in that format is a bad practice in general?

```
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from "@angular/common/http";

constructor(private readonly http: HttpClient) {}

const a = [{a: "a", b: "b"}, {a: "c", b: "d"}];

let p = new HttpParams();

a.forEach(a => {
  p = p.append('test[][test]', a.a);
  p = p.append('test[][lol]', a.b);
});

this.http.get('', {params: p}).subscribe((data) => console.log);
```

Comment: I think it's a good way when you want to covert 2nd nested array to string (**test[][test]**)

Comment: You are doing it too complicated. Create a service which is responsible for a single thing (single responsibility principle). Define the http-call inside that created service with the needed HttpParams (create a method for that). Than call that method and subscribe. https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams#description

Comment: @Codehan25 question is solely about converting objects array to form data format in GET request or finding better way to send that data type over GET. Presented code is just an oversimplified solution to illustrate problem in quick and clear way.